# how can solve floating issues

Tags: html, css

I use CSS to style aside. After applying this style, aside moves to left but I want it at the right of the page. I want aside to have a height that is relational to the container. i.e. I want its bottom margin to touch the top of the footer no matter what is the height of the container.

Style:

```
aside {
width:260px;
float:right;
border-left:1px dashed #aaa;
padding-right:15px;
padding-left:15px;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
overflow:auto;
background-color:blue;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow:0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `position: absolute;`. If you want to keep `position: absolute;` you can add `right: 0;` instead.

```css
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
aside {
width:260px;
float:right;
border-left:1px dashed #aaa;
padding-right:15px;
padding-left:15px;
text-align:center;
overflow:auto;
height: 100%;
background-color:blue;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow:0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<aside>I'm at the right side</aside>
```

Comment: This does not affect the height of the aside!

Answer (score 1):

As Gustaf said, you have to remove the 'position: absolute' to switch the side. To define the height, all the parents of element, needs to have a defined height, so the children element will have a reference to render your own height, like this:

```css
html, body{ 
   height: 100%;
}

aside {
   width:260px;
   float:right;
   border-left:1px dashed #aaa;
   padding-right:15px;
   padding-left:15px;
   text-align:center;
   overflow:auto;
   background-color:blue;
   border-radius:10px;
   box-shadow:0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <aside>I'm at the right side</aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank u. but it is not working and i dont really know why. setting min-height to 100% made the aside height relative to its content